# Compare date from php and MSSQL to retrieve the nearest date from now

Tags: php, sql-server, date, datediff

I want to compare MMSQL date together and i want to retrieve the nearest date from now.

Here is a sample of my mssql date data : 2013-01-23 09:34:03.000

My table is like this:

```
NAME : myTable
 Column:
 - nameUpdate (VARCHAR(255))
  - date (DATETIME)
```

Here is what i've done so far but it won't work.

```
$query = "SELECT date FROM myTable";
$res_mnem = mssql_query($query) or die(mssql_get_last_message() . "[ " . $query . " ]");  
        $latestDate = "";    
        if (!mssql_num_rows($query)) {

             while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($res_mnem)) {
                if($latestDate == ""){
                  $latestDate = $row["date"];
                }
                elseif($row["date"] > $latestDate){
                   $latestDate = $row["date"];
        }
            }

      }
    echo $latestDate;
```

Thanks to all

Comment: In fact the query would be very interesting, at first glance it looks like you could put your date logic into the query itself, instead of in your PHP code.

Comment: I already tried the MAX(date) thing... But its a SELECT date from myTable

Comment: So use a subquery? Post a table schema please.

Comment: @njk : The schema is too simple .. i wrote it down in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATEDIFF(s, [date], GetDate())
FROM myTable
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(s, [date], GetDate())
```

This does a date substraction between Current (GETDATE()) and [date] in your table, on seconds (you could do it at a lower granularity than seconds, if you need to).  It orders by the same datediff, in ascending order.  The top 1 selects only the first record--that's the record that is the closest to the current date because of the ORDER BY.

Comment: If it's possible to have [date]s in the future (don't know what you are tracking, could be future scheduled items or such), just wrap the datediff in an ABS() function to get the nearest date future or past.

Comment: So you could just modify your php to execute this query and retrieve the first (and only) row, rather than having to loop over all the rows.

Comment: The query gives you null, or the php retrieval?

Comment: Maybe diffing off of seconds overflowed. Try changing the datediff in both places use minute: `DATEDIFF(minute, [date], GetDate())`. If that fixes it, let me know and I can suggest how to go about getting something more finegrained than a minute if you need it.